# "Couldn't add widget" in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, widget, fragment

I have problem with adding widget in Fragment. Here is some hardcoded adding 3 example widget:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_widget, container, false);

    mainlayout = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext());
    mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(getContext(), R.id.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);

    addButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.bt_add);
    removeButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.bt_remove);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    removeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(9);
    Log.e(TAG, "createWidget: " + Integer.toString(9) + appWidgetInfo);

    AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(getActivity(), 9, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(9, appWidgetInfo);
    mainlayout.addView(hostView);

    appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(11);
    Log.e(TAG, "createWidget: " + Integer.toString(11) + appWidgetInfo);

    hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(getActivity(), 11, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(11, appWidgetInfo);
    mainlayout.addView(hostView);

    appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(10);
    Log.e(TAG, "createWidget: " + Integer.toString(10) + appWidgetInfo);

    hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(getActivity(), 10, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(10, appWidgetInfo);
    mainlayout.addView(hostView);

    mAppWidgetHost.startListening();
    return root;
}
```

First is OK, second should be weather widget but it show only "Couldn't add widget" and last one is not loading emails.

When I do this in Activity everything works OK. What should I do to make it work in Fragment?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId()` instead of using hardcoded values like `9`, `10`, and `11`?

Comment: It's hardcoded only for make example. Exactly the same code in Activity works.